# view file is not getting picked up by the route when using sub domain

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have created two domains

- abc.com (/domains/abc.com/public_html/)
- admin.abc.com (/domains/abc.com/public_html/admin/)

The first domain has the latest version of the project.
The second domain has the old version of the project with its own .htaccess and .env file

Both directories is having independent full-fledged laravel projects.

abc.com is working fine but admin.abc.com is throwing error saying that it cannot find the blade file. I checked the directory and confirmed that the blade files are present inside (resources/views) directory.

Is there any special settings i need to do to make my sub domain work?
[image]

Comment: Have you tried running the command `php artisan view:clear` incase the view files have been cached?

Answer (score 0):

Run the following artisan comment. It could be that the views are cached:

```
php artisan view:clear
```